# Spring python: how to import another xml resource from within an xml config file

Tags: python, spring

In Java spring one can divide the configuration into multiple xml files and then import one from another using

```
<import resource="importedConfig.xml"/>
```

How to do the same in SpringPython?

Answer (score 0):

While it seems there is no option to include another resource, you can initialize Spring Python using multiple configuration files:

```
configs = [ XMLConfig("config-1.xml"), XMLConfig("config-2.xml") ]
container = ApplicationContext( configs )
```

(Seen in [spring-python source](http://git.springsource.org/spring-python/spring-python/blobs/master/src/springpython/container/__init__.py#line38))